# Can you sell software built with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can you sell software built using Ruby on Rails? If so are there any pitfalls in doing so?

Is it any different to selling software built with PHP for example?

Edit: to elaborate - could I build a forum app like vB and sell that as they do?

Comment: Short answer, yes; The licence covering Rails cannot affect the code you write. Even if you couldn't bundle your code with Rails for redistribution, it doesn't mean you couldn't sell your code. That said Rails is released under the extremely permissive MIT licence, so I wouldn't think you'd have trouble redistributing it, as long as you maintain the LICENCE file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want legal advice ask a lawyer. Any answer given here would be worthless, even if a lawyer did answer they are not "Your" lawyer.

Rails is under the MIT License
Ruby is under the Ruby License

In general you would find your code to be your code.